# Add placeholder instead of value in number and range input when value is 0 - Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, input

I have a number and range input that are working in unison using same value using Angular.js value. When the value is set to 0 (which is what it is by default when page loads `$scope.lbs_needed = 0;`, I want to show a `placeholder="0"` whenever the value of the number or range input is set to 0 that way the 0 value isn't in front of the user's input without them having to manually delete default 0.

Here's my html:

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="number">Pounds of nitrogen desired per acre:</label>
        <input type="number" class="form-control number-input" id="number" ng-model="lbs_needed" ng-change="calculate2()" value="{[{lbs_needed}]}" min="0" max="500" value="{[{lbs_needed}]}" placeholder="0">
        <input type="range" min="0" max="500" class="form-control" id="number" ng-model="lbs_needed" ng-change="calculate2()" value="{[{lbs_needed}]}" placeholder="0">
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, if I understand correctly you want the textbox to have a default value but also want it to be changeable instantly without users having to backspace over the default?

Try this:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('change-default');

input.onfocus = function () {
  if (input.value == 0) {
    input.value = '';
  }
}

input.onblur = function () {
  if (input.value == '') {
    input.value = '0';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="number" placeholder="0" value="0" id="change-default">
```

What I'm doing is listening for an `focus` event, you could also use `addEventListener` instead of `onfocus`.

If the value of the input box is `0` you remove its value ready for the user to type theirs in.